# How do you output a list out without quotes around strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to set up a block to accept only inputs that are in a list but first it asks for the inputs in the input function but I can't seem to get rid of the quotes around the strings in the list. Here is some example code:

```
def Sinput(acceptable):
    while True:
        acceptable = [str(i) for i in acceptable]
        a = input('Enter'+str(acceptable[:-1]).strip('[]')+' or '+str(acceptable[-1]+': '))
        if a in acceptable:
            return a
            break

a = Sinput([ 1, 2.01, '\'cat\'', 'dog'])
print('you entred:', a)
```

The input asks: `Enter'1', '2.01', "'cat'" or dog:` I want it to ask: `Enter 1, 2.01, 'cat' or dog:`

Using `.replace('\'', '')` won't work because the input 'cat' would no longer display correctly

Thanks for any help, I've only been doing coding for about a week.

Comment: The guy below answered it, but you don't need to include the break after the return.

Comment: @tatatat0 Thanks, that was just left over from before I made it a function. Just forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would do good for you:

```
   a = input('Enter {} or {}'.format(' ,'.join(acceptable[:-1]), acceptable[-1]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.join(...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) which is the recommended way for joining an iterable of strings:

```
a = input('Enter'+ ' ,'.join(acceptable[:-1]) + ...)
#                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

P.S. I don't see why you need a `break` after that `return` statement.

Comment: Works ! thanks for the help ! also the break was left over from before I made the block a function just forgot to remove it.